# Downloading HTML page in C# and loading it in memory fastest way

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, httpwebrequest

I have written a following code which downloads a page from a given URL:

```
   string html = string.Empty;
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
   request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
   request.Proxy = null;
   request.ServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
   request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
   request.Method = "GET";
   using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
   using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
   html = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
```

But this takes about 5-8 seconds to download the HTML file which is quite quite slow. My question here is, is there any way to improve this code, or use some other piece of code/library that can perform the HTML download for a given URL faster than this one?

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid I haven't , could you show me an example ? :)

Comment: [Try this](http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-download-a-file-in-c-progressbar-and-download-speed/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an **httpclient** then write the result to a file that way?

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage())
    {
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
        request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute);

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                if (response.Content != null)
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    // write result to file
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```